# Dowonloadable Product with MSI(Multi Source Inventory)

Tags: magento2.3, multi-source-inventory

**I've Magento 2.3 with MSI setup.**

**Please find below screenshot for sources setup.**

[image]

**Please find below screenshot for stocks:**

[image]

I'm stuck where If i create **downloadable product** without assign sources I'm getting error like below:

[image]

How can I create downloadable product along with simple and configurable product ?

If I leave blank than getting error and If i assign sources to product than checkout displays shipping step and shipping method can't load due to its virtual/downloadable product. Cant able to complete payment.

Any ideas ? `I ain't sure It is bug or I'm missing something` ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

does the issue still reproduces to you? Can you please check it out on the latest MSI version, and if it still exists report a bug on MSI GitHub https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/

Answer (score 0):

@Vivek do you have any 3rd party extensions installed which affect the out of the box Inventory implementation, like the one you mentioned in another thread Premium ERP? This could be a root cause of the problem you described here

Comment: Still getting same error and now ERP is removed so no 3rd party modules which affect MSI.